# Profiling a multi-tiered, distributed, web application (server side)

Tags: performance, web-services, web-applications, profiling

I would like to [profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) a complex web application from the server PoV.

According to the wikipedia link above, and the Stack Overflow `profiling` tag description, profiling (in one of its forms) means getting a list (or a graphical representation) of APIs/components of the application, each with the number of calls and time spent in it during run-time.

Note that unlike a traditional one-program/one-language a web server application may be:

- Distributed over multiple machines
- Different components may be written in different languages
- Different components may be running on top of different OSes, etc.

So the traditional "Just use a profiler" answer is not easily applicable to this problem.

I'm ***not*** looking for:

- Coarse performance stats like the ones provided by various *log-analysis tools* (e.g. analog) nor for
- *client-side, per-page* performance stats like the ones presented by tools like Google's Pagespeed, or Yahoo! Y!Slow, waterfall diagrams, and browser component load times)

Instead, I'm looking for a classic profiler-style report:

- number of calls
- call durations

by function/API/component-name, on the *server-side* of the web application.

Bottom line, the question is:

> ***How can one profile a multi-tiered, multi-platform, distributed web application?***

A free-software based solution is much preferred.

I have been searching the web for a solution for a while and couldn't find anything satisfactory to fit my needs except some pretty expensive commercial offerings. In the end, I bit the bullet, thought about the problem, and wrote my own solution which I wanted to freely share.

I'm posting my own solution [since this practice is encouraged on SO](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

This solution is far from perfect, for example, it is at very high level (individual URLs) which may not good for all use-cases. Nevertheless, it has helped me immensely in trying to understand where my web-app spends its time.

In the spirit on open source and knowledge sharing, I welcome any other, especially superior, approaches and solutions from others.

Comment: Any particular reason for the r tag that I'm missing?

Comment: He does use R to aggregation the performance data.  I just dislike the 'here is how I use SO as my blog' aspect of Q+A as essentially one post.

Comment: Dason: sorry, but there was no obvious way to tag the question and the answer separately.  I used R for the solution so that's where the tag came from. Dirk: sorry you feel this way.  SO seems to encourage answering your own question as a way to share knowledge. "answer your own question" was presented to me as an option so I used it. I also see it is a pretty common practice e.g. on the Ubuntu/Unix forums. I had a real problem, thought about it for a while, came up with a solution, so I wanted to share.  Creating an R blog for one post seemed like an overkill.

Comment: Removed the 'r' tag since the question is not R specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thinking of how traditional profilers work, it should be straight-forward to come up with a general free-software solution to this challenge.

Let's break the problem into two parts:

- Collecting the data
- Presenting the data

## Collecting the data

Assume we can break our web application into its individual
constituent parts (API, functions) and measure the time it takes
each of these parts to complete. Each part is called thousands of
times a day, so we could collect this data over a full day or so on
multiple hosts. When the day is over we would have a pretty big and
relevant data-set.

***Epiphany #1:*** substitute '*function*' with '*URL*', and our existing
web-logs are "it".  The data we need is already there:

- Each part of a web API is defined by the request URL (possibly
    with some parameters)
- The round-trip times (often in microseconds) appear on each line
    We have a day, (week, month) worth of lines with this data handy

So if we have access to standard web-logs for all the distributed
parts of our web application, part one of our problem (collecting
the data) is solved.

## Presenting the data

Now we have a big data-set, but still no real insight.
How can we gain insight?

***Epiphany #2:*** visualize our (multiple) web-server logs directly.

A picture is worth a 1000 words.  Which picture can we use?

We need to condense 100s of thousands or millions lines of multiple
web-server logs into a short summary which would tell most of the
story about our performance. In other words: the goal is to generate
a profiler-like report, or even better: a graphical profiler report,
directly from our web logs.

Imagine we could map:

- Call-latencies to one dimension
- Number of calls to another dimension, and
- The function identities to a color (essentially a 3rd dimension)

One such picture: a stacked-density chart of latencies by API
appears below (functions names were made-up for illustrative purposes).

## The Chart:

[image: The 1000 word story: stacked latency distribution of a web application by API]

### Some observations from this example

- We have a tri-modal distribution representing 3 radically
  different 'worlds' in our application:
- The fastest responses, are centered around ~300 microseconds
  of latency. These responses are coming from our varnish cache
- The second fastest, taking a bit less than 0.01 seconds on
  average, are coming from various APIs served by our middle-layer
  web application (Apache/Tomcat)
- The slowest responses, centered around 0.1 seconds and
  sometimes taking several seconds to respond to, involve round-trips
  to our SQL database.

We can see how dramatic caching effects can be on an application
(note that the x-axis is on a log10 scale)

We can specifically see which APIs tend to be fast vs slow, so
we know what to focus on.

We can see which APIs are most often called each day.
We can also see that some of them are so rarely called, it is hard to even see their color on the chart.

## How to do it?

The first step is to pre-process and extract the subset needed-data
from the logs. A trivial utility like Unix '*cut*' on multiple logs
may be sufficient here. You may also need to collapse multiple
similar URLs into shorter strings describing the function/API like
'registration', or 'purchase'. If you have a multi-host unified log
view generated by a load-balancer, this task may be easier. We
extract only the names of the APIs (URLs) and their latencies, so we
end up with one big file with a pair of columns, separated by TABs

```
*API_Name   Latency_in_microSecs*


func_01    32734
func_01    32851
func_06    598452
...
func_11    232734
```

Now we run the R script below on the resulting data pairs to produce
the wanted chart (using Hadley Wickham's wonderful *ggplot2* library).
*Voilla!*

## The code to generate the chart

Finally, here's the code to produce the chart from the API+Latency TSV data file:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript --vanilla
#
# Generate stacked chart of API latencies by API from a TSV data-set
#
# ariel faigon - Dec 2012
#
.libPaths(c('~/local/lib/R',
         '/usr/lib/R/library',
         '/usr/lib/R/site-library'
))

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggplot2))
# grid lib needed for 'unit()':
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(grid))

#
# Constants: width, height, resolution, font-colors and styles
# Adapt to taste
#
wh.ratio = 2
WIDTH = 8
HEIGHT = WIDTH / wh.ratio
DPI = 200
FONTSIZE = 11
MyGray = gray(0.5)

title.theme   = element_text(family="FreeSans", face="bold.italic",
                        size=FONTSIZE)
x.label.theme = element_text(family="FreeSans", face="bold.italic",
                        size=FONTSIZE-1, vjust=-0.1)
y.label.theme = element_text(family="FreeSans", face="bold.italic",
                       size=FONTSIZE-1, angle=90, vjust=0.2)
x.axis.theme  = element_text(family="FreeSans", face="bold",
                        size=FONTSIZE-1, colour=MyGray)
y.axis.theme  = element_text(family="FreeSans", face="bold",
                        size=FONTSIZE-1, colour=MyGray)

#
# Function generating well-spaced & well-labeled y-axis (count) breaks
#
yscale_breaks <- function(from.to) {
    from <- 0
    to <- from.to[2]
    # round to 10 ceiling
    to <- ceiling(to / 10.0) * 10
    # Count major breaks on 10^N boundaries, include the 0
    n.maj = 1 + ceiling(log(to) / log(10))
    # if major breaks are too few, add minor-breaks half-way between them
    n.breaks <- ifelse(n.maj < 5, max(5, n.maj*2+1), n.maj)
    breaks <- as.integer(seq(from, to, length.out=n.breaks))
    breaks
}

#
# -- main
#

# -- process the command line args:  [tsv_file [png_file]]
#    (use defaults if they aren't provided)
#
argv <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
if (is.null(argv) || (length(argv) < 1)) {
    argv <- c(Sys.glob('*api-lat.tsv')[1])
}
tsvfile <- argv[1]
stopifnot(! is.na(tsvfile))
pngfile <- ifelse(is.na(argv[2]), paste(tsvfile, '.png', sep=''), argv[2])

# -- Read the data from the TSV file into an internal data.frame d
d <- read.csv(tsvfile, sep='\t', head=F)

# -- Give each data column a human readable name
names(d) <- c('API', 'Latency')

#
# -- Convert microseconds Latency (our weblog resolution) to seconds
#
d <- transform(d, Latency=Latency/1e6)

#
# -- Trim the latency axis:
#       Drop the few 0.001% extreme-slowest outliers on the right
#       to prevent them from pushing the bulk of the data to the left
Max.Lat <- quantile(d$Latency, probs=0.99999)
d <- subset(d, Latency < Max.Lat)

#
# -- API factor pruning
#       Drop rows where the APIs is less than small % of total calls
#
Rare.APIs.pct <- 0.001
if (Rare.APIs.pct > 0.0) {
    d.N <- nrow(d)
    API.counts <- table(d$API)
    d <- transform(d, CallPct=100.0*API.counts[d$API]/d.N)
    d <- d[d$CallPct > Rare.APIs.pct, ]
    d.N.new <- nrow(d)
}

#
# -- Adjust legend item-height &font-size
#    to the number of distinct APIs we have
#
API.count <- nlevels(as.factor(d$API))
Legend.LineSize <- ifelse(API.count < 20, 1.0, 20.0/API.count)
Legend.FontSize <- max(6, as.integer(Legend.LineSize * (FONTSIZE - 1)))
legend.theme  = element_text(family="FreeSans", face="bold.italic",
                        size=Legend.FontSize,
                        colour=gray(0.3))


# -- set latency (X-axis) breaks and labels (s.b made more generic)
lat.breaks <- c(0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10)
lat.labels <- sprintf("%g", lat.breaks)
#
# -- Generate the chart using ggplot
#
p <- ggplot(data=d, aes(x=Latency, y=..count../1000.0, group=API, fill=API)) +
   geom_bar(binwidth=0.01) +
      scale_x_log10(breaks=lat.breaks, labels=lat.labels) +
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=yscale_breaks) +
      ggtitle('APIs Calls & Latency Distribution') +
      xlab('Latency in seconds - log(10) scale') +
      ylab('Call count (in 1000s)') +
      theme(
            plot.title=title.theme,
            axis.title.y=y.label.theme,
            axis.title.x=x.label.theme,
            axis.text.x=x.axis.theme,
            axis.text.y=y.axis.theme,
            legend.text=legend.theme,
            legend.key.height=unit(Legend.LineSize, "line")
      )

#
# -- Save the plot into the png file
#
ggsave(p, file=pngfile, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, dpi=DPI)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your discussion of "back in the day" profiling practice is true.
There's just one little problem it always had:

- In non-toy software, it may find something, but it doesn't find much, for a [*bunch of reasons*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771).

The thing about opportunities for higher performance is, if you don't find them, the software doesn't break, so *you just can pretend they don't exist*.
That is, until a different method is tried, and they are found.

In statistics, this is called a type 2 error - a *false negative*.
An opportunity is there, but you didn't find it.
What it means is if somebody *does* know how to find it, they're going to win, big time.
[*Here's probably more than you ever wanted to know about that.*](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262)

So if you're looking at the same kind of stuff in a web app - invocation counts, time measurements, you're not liable to do better than the same kind of non-results.

I'm not into web apps, but I did a fair amount of performance tuning in a protocol-based factory automation app many years ago.
I used a logging technique.
I won't say it was easy, but it did work.
The people I see doing something similar is [here, where they use what they call a *waterfall chart*](http://www.strangeloopnetworks.com/blog/how-to-use-a-waterfall-chart-to-interpret-web-performance-data/).
The basic idea is rather than casting a wide net and getting a lot of measurements, you trace through a single logical thread of transactions, analyzing where delays are occurring that don't have to.

So if results are what you're after, I'd look down that line of thinking.

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  I added several clarifications to the original post to make it less ambiguous.  I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @Arielf: The statement is clearer. I tend to make an assumption about goals that maybe you don't share: that what matters is how to make the end software/system/app as fast as possible.

Comment: I share this goal.  But in this particular case, because the client-side tools were widely known and free, I've already done all I could on the page-design/client-side/waterfall-report side and was curious to know more about what's exactly going on on the server side and which parts are the best candidates for optimization.  This is where the question was born.  The results of the graph were largely surprising and eye opening, in many areas though not completely so.

Comment: @arielf: Yes, they are widely known, some are free, the output can be very intriguing and attractive, and *they don't find problems* except little ones. Programmers (not all, just most) have incredibly sloppy thinking about performance. They get it from their teachers, who get it from *their* teachers, but it's based on *nothing*. It's odd, but since they never get called on it, it remains. SO is full of questions about profiler output - what does it mean? That's the point - it doesn't.